# How do I control where `go get` puts things?

Tags: go

When I `go get` a package (say, `godoc`), it wants to create and install it in `/usr/lib/go/bin` (this is an Ubuntu system using the stock Go packages).

This isn't cool, because like a good Debian user I only let .deb packages install stuff into `/usr`.

How do I convince it to install into either my `GOPATH` workspace, or somewhere under `/usr/local`?

Comment: It should stick it in your GOPATH environment variable. [This](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) is a great guide to getting things ironed out.

Comment: It does not stick it there.

Comment: `godoc` is special in that it is part of core tooling, it does not listen to `GOPATH`. Install Go from a correct source, the ubuntu package is clearly missing core features that should be packaged along with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer turned out to be installing the `golang-go.tools` package.

Answer (score 0):

If you install Go with GVM instead of from apt they will be placed in ~/.gvm/gos/ or your $GOPATH instead.

https://github.com/moovweb/gvm

Also I don't think godoc comes with 1.3 anymore, it has to be installed from go.tools

http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/godoc

http://golang.org/doc/go1.2#go_doc

> The "go doc" command is deleted.